# do-while error boolean?

Tags: java, do-while

```
    Player Anfallare = new Player("A");
    Player Forsvarare = new Player("F");

    Anfallare.armees = 10;
    Forsvarare.armees = 10;
 do{
    Risk.status();

 }while(Anfallare.armees = 0 OR Forsvarare.armees = 0);
```

I would like to do something like this, that it should keep on `status()` until one of `Anfallare.armees` or `Forsvarare.armees` is `0`.

This i made doesnt work though, i get required `boolean`, found `int`, how can i do this right?

Comment: You are programming a Risk game, right? :p

Comment: @Marcelo this is true :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keep on status() until one of Anfallare.armees or Forsvarare.armees is 0

Since you want to run `status()` **until** one of those values is 0, you need to negate the whole thing:

```
do {
    Risk.status();
} while (Anfallare.armees != 0 && Forsvarare.armees != 0);
```

Translated this means: do `status()` while both the `armees` are non-zero -- so this has the same meaning as "until one of them is 0".

The condition could also be written as the negation of what you wrote:

```
while (! (Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0) )
```

But I think the first version is easier to read...

Comment: I would've preferred "while (Anfallare.armees > 0 && Forsvarare.armees > 0)".

Answer (score 1):

Change your while-condition to

```
while(Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0)
```

In java "or" is `||` and test on equality is `==`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
do {
   ...
} while(Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0);
```

The equality operator is `==` and not `=` (that is the assignment operator). Also, a logical OR in Java is represented by `||` and not `OR`.